How to get LP total Supply and LP Burn, i have lp not burn
using the solana/web3.js , spl and sdk raydium libraries.
in typescript I can get the remaining lp mint by getAccountInfo
but I can't find what to do for the total and I don't want to use rugcheck
thanks
